# Elixir - getting the values in args, passed from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, elixir

I'm tasked with creating a server (which uses Elixir and Merigo SDE) for a Unity game.

For now, I'm content with sending data from Unity (C#), which I do as follows:

```
public class ShotController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ConnectionHandler conHandler;
    public void Shoot(Vector3 direction, float power) {
        DataToSend data = new DataToSend();
        data.power = power;
        data.direction_x = direction.x;
        data.direction_y = direction.y;
        conHandler.SendShotDetails(data);
    }
}

public class DataToSend
{
    public float power = 0;
    public float direction_x = 0;
    public float direction_y = 0;
}

public class ConnectionHandler : MonoBehaviour, Playground.App.IPlaygroundDelegate
{
    public void SendShotDetails<T>(T data) where T : class
    {
        Debug.Log("Shot!");
        Playground.App.Manager.LocalGame.ScriptRequest("test_action", data);
    }
}
```

On the merigo's side, I have this:

```
# Test receive request
def doRequest("test_action", args) do
    # Read the player data
    Sys.Log.debug("Test action fired... #{inspect args}")
    %{:results => "success"}
end
```

Now, save for some errors with Unity, the Elixir side does work; it displays the following:

> Test action fired... %{"direction_x" => 0.9692893624305725,
> "direction_y" => 0.0, "power" => 12.293679237365723}

But I have no idea how to get those values from args and return them back. `args.power` didn't work.

Is there something else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map has its keys as *strings* aka *binaries*. Dot notation works for maps if and only keys are atoms.

You have two options.

Either get to the value through [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html)

```rb
map =
  %{"direction_x" => 0.9692893624305725,
    "direction_y" => 0.0,
    "power" => 12.293679237365723
  }
map["power"]
#⇒ 12.293679237365723
```

Or, alternatively, pattern-match it directly in the function clause

```
def do_request("test_action", %{"power" => power}) do
  Sys.Log.debug("power is #{power}")
end
```

or, destructure it:

```rb
def do_request("test_action", args) do
  %{"power" => power} = args
  Sys.Log.debug("power is #{power}")
end
```

---

*Sidenotes:* by convention, functions in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are named in underscore notation (`do_request` instead of `doRequest`,) and when the map keys are atoms, we use shorter notation with a colon `:` (instead of `%{:results => "success"}` do `%{results: "success"}`.)